# how to approve or reject record on user side on admin's approval in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner with asp.net and MVC. I want to approve or reject record from admin side,if approve button is clicked 
from admin side only that record will be shown on user side otherwise not.I have took a **IsShow** db column as **bit** datatype in database and based on that i want approve or reject the record.Can anybody help me with this please, i tried following thing should i do this with Jquery or plain c# code will do. I searched for this but could not got the satisfactory answer

```
 My Model

 public partial class UserComments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsShow { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method in admin side from which admin view for approval and rejection is done

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.UserComments.ToList().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id));
    }
```

My controller Method from user side from which users view is showed

```
    public ActionResult Gandhiji(int? id)
    {

        ViewBag.user = db.UserComments.Where(c => c.Id == 1).OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();

        return View("Gandhiji");
    }
```

User side view where i want to show approved record

```
        @{
            var Users = (IEnumerable<UserComments>)ViewBag.user;
        }

        @foreach (var item in Users)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">

                    @*<div class="panel-body EApic" style="background: url(/Pictures/@p.ImagPath) no-repeat; background-size:cover;">*@
                    <div class="panel-body EApic" id="imagediv" style="background: url(/Pictures/@item.Path) no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
                        <div class="EAtext">
                                @Html.Raw(item.Name)
                                <br />
                                @Html.Raw(item.Comment)
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    @*closing divs of row*@
                </div>

            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

admin side view

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="@item.Path" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="show" data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Show</a> |
                <a href="#" id="hide" data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Hide</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<script>
    $(function () {
        ("#show").click(function () {
            $('#imagediv').html("");
            $('#imagediv').load('@Url.Action("Gandhiji", "Home")');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Approving records means any column for example isApproved value to do it from false to true. You need to update table against id of that record.

There are couple of ways to resolve this issue. You can detach the old object before you attach the new instance

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{ 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var OldInsObj = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
            DateTime UsersDateCreated = OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated;

            user.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;
            user.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.Entry(OldInsObj).State = EntityState.Detached;

            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

You can update the entity instance retrieved from database.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
{ 
        var user = db.Users.Find(userId);

        if (TryUpdateModel(user))
        {                
            user.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;

            user.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

Or you can use Automapper to copy the values of user instance to the OldInsObj instance.

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{ 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var OldInsObj = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
            DateTime UsersDateCreated = OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated;

            OldInsObj = Mapper.Map(user);

            OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;
            OldInsObj.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

You can also return json if you are on the same view from which you are approving the record and after approve you wan to display message on the same page.